# How to Convert Row_number with Common table expression query to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, database-migration, common-table-expression, row-number

The following query contains SQL with `ROW_NUMBER()` over a windowing function and a common table expression:

```
WITH numbered AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY master_id, Report_id
    ORDER BY master_id, Report_id
  ) AS _dupe_num 
  FROM #tradePositionFilterInfo
  WHERE 1=1
)
DELETE FROM numbered
WHERE _dupe_num > 1
```

How can I convert this to work in MySQL?

Comment: Is there an id column in `#tradePositionFilterInf`? Or a timestamp? Something to break a tie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql's multitable delete syntax:

```
delete a
from #tradePositionFilterInf a, #tradePositionFilterInf b
where a.master_id = b.master_id
and a.Report_id = b.Report_id
and a.id > b.id
```

The last line is the key. I chose the `id` column to break ties, assuming there will be such a column. If not, use `timestamp` or similar. If no time-based column, use any column that's different. If all columns are identical, you're hosed.